# I can't seem to get multiple line inputs into multiple variables in my code

Tags: c

I need to be able to input two variables as they pass through two if statements to get specific data from a dataset but I can't seem to get two variable inputs. I've tried using two scanf_s and putting a fflush(stdin) inbetween but I still can't get it to input two variables so I thought I'd try doing two inputs in one scanf_s and I need to separate the inputs with a return as the first input can have two words in it so will be an issue to make both variable inputs on one line.

Here is my code for the section

```
void filterByStationAndSensorType(TelemetryData* telemetryArray, int arraySize) {
    char stationType[34];
    char sensorType[20];
    printf("Enter the Station to filter: ");

#if (_MSC_VER > 1600)
    scanf_s("%34s[^\n]", stationType,
           (unsigned)(sizeof(stationType) / sizeof(stationType[0]))),
           "%19s", sensorType,
           (unsigned)(sizeof(sensorType) / sizeof(sensorType[0]));
#else
    scanf("%19s", stationType);
    scanf("%19s", sensorType);
#endif

    printf("Telemetry Data for Station '%s':\n", stationType);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        if (strstr(telemetryArray[i].location, stationType) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(telemetryArray[i].sensorType, sensorType) == 0) {
                printf("SensorID: %s, SensorType: %s, Location: %s, Measurement: %.2f, "
                    "Status: %s\n",
                    telemetryArray[i].sensorID, telemetryArray[i].sensorType,
                    telemetryArray[i].location, telemetryArray[i].measurement,
                    telemetryArray[i].status);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n\nArraySize: %i\n\n", arraySize);
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%...", variable, "%...", variable)` that's not going to work. The format for `scanf_s` works exactly the same as for plain `scanf`.

Comment: Furthermore, passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as leading to undefined behavior. Please try to not use it that way.

Comment: Oh, and `"%34s[^\n]"` is the format `%34s` (which is too much for your array) followed by the verbatim string `[^\n]` which `scanf_s` tries to do an exact match for. A better solution here, IMO, is to use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a whole line, then just [remove the trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Comment: If you persist in using `scanf` (or `scanf_s` or other related functions) then always check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: One of the primary benefits of `scanf_s` (vs. `scanf`) is that [AFAICT] there doesn't need to be a length/count in the format specifier. So, you don't have to change the format if the `char` array length changes. And, the length is the length of the var and _not_ one less. That is: `scanf("%33s%19s",stationType,sensorType);` --> `scanf_s("%s%s",stationType,(unsigned) sizeof(stationType),sensorType,(unsigned) sizeof(sensorType));`